# How to execute dynamic stored procedure in ASP.NET MVC using Entity Framework and send result to view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures, dynamic

I have created a dynamic stored procedure (using Pivot). I have no idea about the columns returned by the stored procedure. So I am not able to create a viewmodel class.

I searched and found this method to execute stored procedure:

```
public List<dynamic> GetData(int CurriculumID)
{  
    var data = context.Database.SqlQuery<dynamic>("MyProcedureName @CurriculumId", new SqlParameter("CurriculumId", CurriculumID)).ToList();
    return data;
 }
```

Now I am not sure how to send this data to razor view and create dynamic table based on the data. Any guidance?

I am also not able to view data here is how I am getting it:

[image]

Comment: I don't know what `MyProcedureName` returns, can you provide table structure behind it? Since return type is `List<dynamic>`, read this first: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23670408/how-to-fetch-data-from-listdynamic.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic Object Intellisense](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11289995/dynamic-object-intellisense)

Comment: MyProcedureName is returning n number of columns.. Sometimes only 2 columns sometimes 50 columns